# Two consecutive httpwebRequests in c#

Tags: c#, web, request

Is it possible to make two consecutive web requests in c#? So make the inital request and then make a request from that response. I am doing this to fill out two consecutive forms in a c# program.

```
string postdata = "param1=...&param2=..."

var data1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data1.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data1, 0, data1.Length);
    }



    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

So if this is my first form how would I then go and fill out the second form that the completion of this form should lead to?

Comment: Yes, the same way you make a single request.

Comment: So what would the code for this look like?

Comment: @juliacas: Exactly like sending a single request.

Comment: Don't paste code into comments.  Edit the question and paste it there.  (Code in comments is pretty much unreadable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a (very) stripped down version of some code using `HttpWebRequest` that can send a request either via parameters or content but assumes either (or both) are objects passed in. E.g., if you need to send parameters like `login` and `password` usage would look like;

```
var response = HttpUtilities.Post("http://www.someurl.com/", new { login = "user", password = "1234");
// check response data + codes, etc...
var secondResponse = HttpUtilities.Post("http://www.someurl.com/page2", new { data = "stuff" });
```

The code below won't necessarily compile as I had to strip it down manually and is untested in its current form but it gives a very good idea of what's needed to check the response, debug, etc.;

```
namespace Helpers.Web
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Cache;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Web;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using NLog;

    public class HttpUtilities
    {
        #region NLog instance
        /// <summary>
        /// The single instance of an NLog LogManager for this class.
        /// </summary>
        private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public static TResponse Post<TResponse, TContent>(string uri, object parameters = null, TContent content = null)
            where TContent : class
        {
            return GetResponse<TResponse, TContent>(uri, SerializeToQueryString(parameters),
                                                    content, HttpMethod.Post);
        }

        public static HttpWebResponse GetResponse<TContent>(string uri,
                                                            string parameters,
                                                            TContent content,
                                                            HttpMethod method)
            where TContent : class
        {
            // build the full URL if parameters have been specified
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters))
            {
                uri += "?" + parameters;
            }

            // make the request and send back the results
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = BuildWebRequest(uri, content, method);
            return GetWebResponse(uri, webRequest);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private static HttpWebRequest BuildWebRequest<TContent>(string uri, TContent content, HttpMethod method)
            where TContent : class
        {
            // get the request details
            _logger.Trace("Building request for [{0}]", uri);

            // set the web request details
            _logger.Trace("Setting request header details...");
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            webRequest.Method = method.ToString();
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            webRequest.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

            // do we have content to insert
            string serializedContent = string.Empty;
            if (content != null)
            {
                JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    // ignore the self referencing nature of EntityFramework objects and skip
                    // over the self references when serializing
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                };

                // serialize the object as json and convert it into bytes we can
                // inject into the content stream of the request.
                serializedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, jsonSettings);
                UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] byteContent = encoding.GetBytes(serializedContent);
                webRequest.ContentLength = byteContent.Length;

                // write the content
                // NOTE: the act of writing out the data actually sends the request!
                _logger.Trace("Sending request and getting response from [{0}]", uri);
                using (var contentStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    contentStream.Write(byteContent, 0, byteContent.Length);
                }
                _logger.Trace("Injected content into request to [{0}]. Content: {1}", uri, serializedContent);
            }
            else
            {
                // if there's no content then we haven't actually sent the request yet. However we still
                // need to set the header details.
                webRequest.ContentLength = 0;
                _logger.Trace("Sending request and getting response from [{0}]", uri);
            }

            return webRequest;
        }

        private static HttpWebResponse GetWebResponse(string uri, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response;
            try
            {
                _logger.Debug("Sending [{0}] request to [{1}]...", webRequest.Method, webRequest.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
                response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                // we might still have response information on the request
                // if this is so, then extract it and log it as we'll need to
                // find out what the server actually replied with in order to debug
                // what went on
                _logger.Error(wex, "There was a problem getting a response from the server");
                if (wex.Response != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // NOTE: this can be caused by the server returning a YSOD. You can see the formatted result
                        //       in debug mode by using the HTML visualizer when looking at the content of the
                        //       wResponseContent variable.
                        _logger.Debug("Attempting to extract server response details from WebException...");
                        using (Stream wResponseStream = wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            if (wResponseStream != null)
                            {
                                using (StreamReader wStreamReader = new StreamReader(wResponseStream))
                                {
                                    string wResponseContent = wStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                                    _logger.Debug(wex, "Received fault response from [{0}]. Response: {1}",
                                        uri, wResponseContent);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception eex)
                    {
                        // there was an issue trying to get the response content from the original error.
                        // There's nothing more we can do except log this exception and rethrow the
                        // original.
                        _logger.Fatal(eex, "There was a problem getting response details from a WebException raised from the server");
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Debug("No response data present in the exception.");
                }

                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex, "There was a problem getting a response from [{0}]", uri);
                throw;
            }
            return response;
        }

        private static string SerializeToQueryString(object parameters)
        {
            // if we weren't given anything then there's nothing we can do
            if (parameters == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            if (parameters is string)
            {
                return parameters as string;
            }

            // iterate over the parameter properties and build the query string
            Type type = parameters.GetType();
            BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance
                                 | BindingFlags.GetProperty
                                 | BindingFlags.Public;
            if (type.IsInterface)
            {
                // if the type is an interface, only get the interface's members
                flags |= BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
            }

            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(flags);
            List<string> urlParameters = new List<string>();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
            {
                // convert the value to a string first so that we can make it safe
                // to put into the URL
                _logger.Trace("Getting value from {0}.{1} [{2}]", type.FullName, prop.Name, prop.PropertyType.FullName);
                object rawValue = prop.GetValue(parameters, null);
                string propertyValue = string.Empty;
                if (rawValue != null)
                {
                    propertyValue = rawValue.ToString();
                }

                urlParameters.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", prop.Name, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(propertyValue)));
            }

            return string.Join("&", urlParameters.ToArray());
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```